# Delphi embed DLL into executable without use of resources

Tags: delphi, dll

I want do exactly this: 
[embed DLL into EXE](http://www.360doc.com/content/14/0113/06/9200790_344753741.shtml)
but without using of resources (the DLL binary should not be visible in resource viewer but stay hidden inside of the executable code).
I tried to convert the file into string literal(s) but the file is too big and I only get out of memory or stack overflow exceptions when trying to compile it:

```
const cFileSize = 2424564;
const cFileBlock =
'30820274020100300D06092A864886F70D010101'+
'05000482025E3082025A02010002818100D713B2'+
...
'BF1F8167F517D3945C27CABCB1E7D7C4092336B9';
```

What do you suggest:

a)try some means to meet compiler memory limitations (like split to more include files etc.)?

b)convert the DLL to object file and link it with the application (which tool?)

c)some other way?

Thank you

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: What a great idea. Nobody will ever find it!!!!

Comment: You could embed it in an asm function with a load of dd statements. But, as I said, you won't fool anyone. And the AV software won't like it.

Comment: @Martin: This should be part of software copy protection (yes I know that every protection can be cracked).

Comment: All you will succeed in doing is to make your program harder to maintain and likely to be treated as malware. If you want to secure your program, ask an expert. You'll just waste your own time and make things worse.

Comment: Is this your own DLL? If so, why not just put the code you need directly in your app and forget about using a DLL?

Comment: @David: Well, the experts (who make the DLL) say to load the DLL into memory then verify it matches the expected signature and then call LoadLibrary and make further calls to it. I just thought above could be even better (single step) solution. But if antimalware programs detect all such techniques as potential malware threats then of course it is unusable.

Comment: @Jerry: No it is a DLL of other vendor - we will use it to protect our software.

Comment: Ignoring the A/V issue that others have mentioned, and which may very well be completely valid, what you suggest above should work in principle. Using a string is sub-optimal, though. Instead do `const cFileBlock: array[0..2424564-1] of byte = ($30, $82, ..., $B9);`.

Comment: You may put it as a part of the form - but form itself is DFM-type custom resource

Comment: However extracting binary modules "on the run" is not very usual pattern. some SysInternals toosl do it- but they extract custom-tailored pre OS kernel driver. Basically, that is not how programs usually work. So for any cracker you basically light the candle in the night - here something unusual going on! Look here!  You can not make descent anti-crack protection without embedding parts of protection into EXE itself. And your "matches the expected signature" sounds like Delphi XE4 enhanced protection. Well, it made the life worse for legal users, crackers were not affected much.

Comment: Somewhat philosophical observation: I have legal DVD's with S.t.a.l.k.e.r. and Fallout 3 games. Despite having them I always played their cracked copies. Why ? Because the protection their made them instable and inconvenient. As a result their cracked version for me the consumer were of better quality than their not-yet-cracked versions. It was not a matter of money - I have legal disks - it was a matter of user experience. If you want to put ball and chain upon your customer leg, you better make sure he really cannot escape. You scheme does not do it.

Comment: @Arioch: You are basically right, because even when I use the DLL in a standard way the communication with licensing server slows down application start (it is not Delphi XE4 protection). But some way of protection is necessary to keep honest people honest and we have no time and experience to write our own licensing solution completely. I'll try the array of byte solution tomorrow just to prove it works but we won't use it because of the AV risks mentioned above.

Comment: ASProtect, Sentinel and many others - there are many protection vendors, stick with those that do inject into your EXE, into the sources or as an exe post-processor/wrapper. Basically what you want to do is https://familynow.com/images/fail-owned-fence-security-fail.jpg

I would not break into your DLL (the iron door), I would step aside and break into your unprotected code that loads the DLL, making it load my substitution instead. Yep, you would extract your DLL, but you would only call mine

Comment: So, basically, should your customers be able (themselves or ask some third party) to run your program through TurboDebugger (or any other debugger) ? If they are not - you can implement some per-Windows (approx. per-Machine) activation using Windows XP+ Crypto API and All-Users-readable file to store activation data. No need for something more complex than that. But if they can then those DLLs tricks add literally nothing! They add the iron door - but mount that iron door into the paper wall. They would not attack the DLL itself, but the non-protected loading sequence

Comment: PS you may even zip that DLL and use some open-key (aka asymmetric, aka two-keys) cipher to make it both smaller and look less like DLL. Still that would add nothing but thin veil of obfuscation for static-analysis. Behavior analysis would instantly ring at the exact place you start running the protection.  One of the most basic things in protection is obfuscation of "cause and effect" chains. And you clearly call any cracker to "check this DLL and all accesses to it - they are suspicious!". Poor idea. If your protection vendor can not embed it into your EXE - then i'd not trust them

Comment: @Arioch: They can inject their DLL into final wrapped EXE as well but there were some other problems with that solution, so we were recommended to use external DLL solution. They can wrap EXE even without the DLL so it should be IMO harder to modify the EXE. It was only my idea to do the thing above to increase the protection degree even further but I don't want to risk some AV false warnings, as I've already said.

Comment: the protection code should be intertwined with your original code so there would be no way to separate one from another. At very least part that checks identity of DLL and loads it should work already under protection. So that DLL can only be additional extra model, but the core of the protection should be inseparably intertwined within main EXE code

Comment: Don't struggle. Release under GPL.

Comment: @Arioch: I can wrap the entire exe so the part checking the identity works under protection. I can run/attach the exe in misc. debuggers but it is useless for me (I cannot see referenced strings, etc.).

Comment: @Free Consulting: I don't want to stop profi hackers I just want keep honest people honest, as I said. I suppose we will slightly change the protection mechanism at each update. Release under GPL is something we cannot afford.

Comment: @tk_ it is not often that one searches for "reference strings" - because crackers simply does not know ones. Searched are behaviour patterns. So in your case the cracker would use trivial Process Monitor, would see you extracted the protection DLL and would set the breakpoint in debugger on writing that DLL and on loading it, then they would see the difference in the paths wit hand without DLLs and patch the if-then-els or something like that

Comment: @Arioch. Yep it was only one thing. I've been searching for those then intermodular calls and other patterns. I've "modified" some commercial software packages myself but many years ago and just for fun (and not having to carry some stupid hw keys along with me:-). But now I am lazy to do it:-) I just tried shortly with OllyDebugger (I do not have SoftIce anymore installed) on the wrapped exe and realized I would stay honest:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm that solution proposed in the comments above works:

```
const cFileBlock: array[0..2424564-1] of byte = ($30, $82, ..., $B9);
```

The compiler does not complain about stack overflows and out of memory errors anymore.

But I will not use this solution anyway because of possible false threat warnings from antivirus software, see the comments above again.

Thank you all for help.

Comment: What's the compilation time like, out of interest? FWIW, it's going to be pretty easy for any attacker to find the data. Only mildly harder than a resource.

Comment: Compilation is slightly slower. To make it harder for the attacker to find the library data by the DLL signature etc. I can imagine to compress the DLL with some custom compression utility before generating the array from it. It would further speed up the compilation. I'll give it a try. At runtime the DLL will be decompressed first, then loaded with BTMemorymodule and then used. It works with BTmemoryModule w/o problems, we've tested on 5 different PCs (Win7,8,10) and Avast, Norton and Eset did not complain. But we will test more, then make final decision.

Comment: A compressed resource would be no less secure in my view and easier to managed. Personally I'd just deploy the dll on disk but I already said that!!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a CRC checksum ?

If your goal is to ensure that the DLL has not been tampered with in any way, you can store a CRC in your program which is calculated from a known untampered DLL.  Then later, simply read in the DLL and compare the calculated checksum of that DLL with what you have stored.

One thing to watch out for is if the person/company that produces the DLL makes a change, then a different checksum will result and this updated checksum will need to be stored in your application or else the program will "believe" the DLL has been tampered with if the updated version is used.